# Playframework [Java]: Mailer plugin don't work with an email created with plesk

Tags: java, playframework, mailing

I created this e-mail address with plesk via my vps : ex@example.com. I know this is working, because it sends the auto reply. 
I was working with another email (i.e., Gmail) and sending newsletters and invoices to client with plugin named [Play-Mailer](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer)  (working with play framework java 2.6). This was working fine with Gmail configuration :

```
 play.mailer {
  host=smtp.gmail.com
  port=465
  ssl=true
  tls=false
  user=example-user
  password=*****
  debug=false
  mock=false
}
```

When I try to use my own email :

```
play.mailer {
  host=example.org /*i tried smtp.example.org also */  
  port=465
  ssl=false
  tls=false
  user= campus
  password=*****
  debug=true
  mock=false
}
```

Every time i get this error :

```
Execution exception
[EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : example.org:465]
```

Answer (score 0):

The port you are using is`465` and therefore the  SSL should be `true`, and the mailing host should also be `smtp.example.org`.

The port 465 relates to SMTP and the SSL is used for the communication.